# Wrapping long text into a container, causes overflow Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, overflow

I'm creating a notification center for my application, and it contains a bit of long strings for the title and the body, and it always causes overflow, I've tried using Expanded widgets, and these following stack over flow questions: [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930754/flutter-wrapping-text), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53910087/wrap-text-in-container-without-using-a-fixed-width-in-flutter) But I cannot apply it to my code, here is what it looks like right now:

[image]

I get the text from my firebase cloud firestore, and I'm outputting the texts using a listview.

The **title text** is this: "Allen Indefenzo has rescinded consent for you to access his/her data"
The **body text** is this : "He/she has removed all your access and you will no longer be able to view / change his data, to have access again ask for the user to give you his/her special code again."

Here is my code:

```
Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: db
              .collection('users')
              .document(userData.userID)
              .collection('notifications')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.data.documents.length != 0) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 150,
                          width: 100,
                          child: Image(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                                snapshot.data.documents[index]['dpURL']), fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              height: 50,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                              child:
                                  Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['title']),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 50,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                              child:
                                  Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['body']),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Any help is appreciated and if you can explain it would be amazing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to wrap your `Column` inside `Expanded`,

```
 Container(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 150,
                    width: 100,
                    child: Image(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQLBtBU3nUOK7osT41ZsQhP4VBV7fd9euqXvXVKQH0Q7bl4txeD'),
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                            'Reallly looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong textttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt'),
                        Text(
                            'Reallly looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong textttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
```

output:

[image]

---

Additionally if you want to limit lines of `Text` use,

```
  Text(
'Reallly looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongtextttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt',
    maxLines: 2,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your column inside expanded widget

```
Expanded(child: 
               Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              height: 50,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                              child:
                                  Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['title']),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 50,
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                              child:
                                  Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['body']),
                            ),
                          ],
      ),
),
```

Expanded widget is useful when you want to fill all the remaining space when a column or row widget have 2 or more child widgets. so wrapping a child inside an expanded widget will fill up the remaining space accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
return Container(child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                height: 150,
                                width: 100,
                                child: Image(
                                  image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data.documents[index]['dpURL']), fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                ),
                              ),
                             new Expanded(
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                      child: TitleText(
                                        text:snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'] ,
                                        maxLine: 5,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      height: 50,
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                                      child: TitleText(
                                          text:snapshot.data.documents[index]['body']),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
```